# A code is being called more than once inside of a controller in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, alert, watch, document-ready

I have the following code in Angular Js

**moduel.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) 
{

   alert("Hellow World");

   //Some code....

});
```

The above **alert box is getting displayed more than once**. I am able to see this 4-5 times when I run the above code.

So i tried to place the same code in **document.ready function** inside the controller...

```
angular.element(document)
  .ready(function () 
  {
  });
```

But still I am able to see alert displaying more than once in the page.

I heard the reasons for this could be $watch on which I don't have any idea.

Actually i have a very big function, which is being called more than once. For simplifying this I added alert() box instead of function. then I came to know that default variables, alert() boxes and function calls are triggering more than once in the page.

Comment: Show your HTML of where this controller is being instantiated

Comment: Pst HTML code, the problem is there.